# AWS Cognito Signin via Get Session not syncing with identity pool

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

After signing a user up, I'm logging them in via getSession. If I use the interactive sign in, via AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate, then it signs me in properly but via getSession I'm not able to do so. Here's my code.

After calling getSession, I'm getting, the user.isSignedIn is true but 
AWSSignInManager.shared.isLoggedIn is false, also AWSIdentityManager.default.identityId is null

When I make the call credentialsProvider!.getIdentityId(), it returns the error "Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.}"

Whats more interesting is that this works when the app's a fresh install but doesn't after I do a separate login + logout.

I'm making the following calls:
1) self.pool?.signUp(email, password: password, userAttributes: attributes, validationData: nil)
2) newUser?.getSession(email, password: password, validationData: nil)
3) credentialsProvider!.getIdentityId()
4) credentialsProvider?.credentials()

Here's my signup + sign in code: (I've removed the error prompts and logs for brevity)

```
        self.pool?.signUp(email, password: password, userAttributes: attributes, validationData: nil).continueWith {[weak self] (task: AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse>) -> AnyObject? in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return nil }
        if let error = task.error as NSError? {
            return nil
        }

        guard let signupResponse = task.result else {
            print("Error : No Signup Response")
            return nil
        }
        newUser = signupResponse.user
        return newUser?.getSession(email, password: password, validationData: nil)
        }
        .continueWith(block: {[weak self] (task) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return nil }


            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                        return
            }
            guard let signinResponse = task.result else {
                print("Error : No Sign-in Response")
                return nil
            }

            let identityPoolId = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!.nestedDict(key: "AWS").nestedDict(key: "CredentialsProvider").nestedDict(key: "CognitoIdentity").nestedDict(key: "Default")["PoolId"] as! String

            credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: identityPoolId)
            let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
                region: .USEast1,
                credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
            AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
            return credentialsProvider!.getIdentityId()
        })
        .continueWith(block: { (task) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error {
                print("GetIdentityId Error:\(error)")
                // Handle error
            }
            // GetCredentialsForIdentity
            let cognitoId = task.result
            return credentialsProvider?.credentials()
        }).continueWith(block: {
            (task: AWSTask) -> Void in
            if let _ = task.error {
                print("Credentials Error:")
                // Handle error
            }
            print("Task:\(task)")
            self.onSignIn()
            })
        })
```